# Two independent async loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, event-loop

What would be a good approach to execute two asynchronous loops running in parallel in Python, using `async/await`?

I've thought about something like the code below, but can't wrap my head around how to use `async`/`await`/`EventLoop` in this particular case.

```
import asyncio

my_list = []

def notify():
    length = len(my_list)
    print("List has changed!", length)

async def append_task():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        await my_list.append(random.random())
        notify()

async def pop_task():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.8)
        await my_list.pop()
        notify()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(append_task())
loop.create_task(pop_task())
loop.run_forever()
```

Expected output:

```
$ python prog.py
List has changed! 1 # after 1sec
List has changed! 0 # after 1.8sec
List has changed! 1 # after 2sec
List has changed! 2 # after 3sec
List has changed! 1 # after 3.6sec
List has changed! 2 # after 4sec
List has changed! 3 # after 5sec
List has changed! 2 # after 5.4sec
```

Comment: So what output are you getting instead? `BaseEventLoop` is not a concrete loop implementation; use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` to get a concrete loop for your platform.

Comment: Also, `list` operations are not awaitable. `time.sleep()` won't yield to other coroutines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this works fine:

note: you wanted to await fast non-io bound operations (`list.append` and `list.pop` that are not even coroutines); what you can do is `await`[`asyncio.sleep(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) (which is a coroutine and yield control back to the caller):

```
import asyncio
import random

my_list = []


def notify():
    length = len(my_list)
    print("List has changed!", length)

async def append_task():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        my_list.append(random.random())
        notify()

async def pop_task():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1.8)
        my_list.pop()
        notify()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
cors = asyncio.wait([append_task(), pop_task()])
loop.run_until_complete(cors)
```

`time.sleep` itself is blocking and does not play nicely with `await`.

Comment: could you explain what to do if I do have a blocking function (such as time.sleep())? All examples use this asyncio.sleep(), but I have actual long computations (or i/o bound stuff), and it's unclear to me how to wrap it such that this example would work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fab: asyncio will not help with cpu-bound functions. and if your i/o-bound stuff is not built on asyncio it will not work either (that is why `time.sleep()` does not work, but `asyncio.sleep()` does.) you need to call coroutines that yield the program flow back to the caller to get a benefit from the async loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, hiro. That clears things up considerably. I've been looking in the wrong place then!

Comment: Asyncio not available on 2.7.

Comment: @rbonallo that is true. but as the question is about `asyncio` it is about python 3. or what is your point?

Comment: No point, just to save people spending 5 mins pip installing, googling error and realizing it is sadly not available on 2.7.

Comment: @rbonallo ah, ok! thanks for clarifying! will edit the question and add the python 3 tag. that may make it a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

List objects do not have awaitable operations, nor do they need to as there is no I/O or other delay you could handle asynchronously.

You also want to use `asyncio.sleep()`, not `time.sleep()`; the latter *blocks*.

The following works just fine; I added in a timestamp in the `notify` to show this off better:

```
from datetime import datetime
# ...

start = datetime.now()
def notify():
    length = len(my_list)
    print("t: {:.1f}, List has changed! {}".format(
        (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds(), length))

async def append_task():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        my_list.append(random.random())
        notify()

async def pop_task():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1.8)
        my_list.pop()
        notify()
```

Note that we use `await` on the `asyncio.sleep()` call; that provides a point where your coroutine (*cooperative* routine) yields control to another routine.

This produces:

```
$ python asyncio_demo.py
t: 1.0, List has changed! 1
t: 1.8, List has changed! 0
t: 2.0, List has changed! 1
t: 3.0, List has changed! 2
t: 3.6, List has changed! 1
t: 4.0, List has changed! 2
t: 5.0, List has changed! 3
t: 5.4, List has changed! 2
t: 6.0, List has changed! 3
```